# Two text inputs, one submit button. When submitting the form, value of first input appears in the other input with jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form action="" id="form2">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="third">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_form">
  </div>

</form>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="fourth">
</div>
```

Two text inputs, one submit button. When submitting the form, value of first input appears in the other input in jQuery or JS?

After submitting the form the input value displayed in another input field.

How can I make this work by using JavaScript or jQuery only?

Comment: Are you asking or saying ? Is it happening or you want it to happen ?

Comment: I am asking for solution. how it's possible?

Comment: What is the meaning when submitting will wipe out the current page?You can do this by simple button also

Comment: Exactly, you can either make the submit button a simple button or save the value you get from the "third" text box in cookies and set the text in "fourth" text box when page refreshes by checking if that cookie is set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `button` instead of `submit` input type, Here you go:

```js
$('#submit_form').click(function(){
  
    $('#fourth').val($('#third').val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form2">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="third">
            <input type="button" id="submit_form" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="fourth">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is correct but I want to provide a solution with only javascript.
You can use button and give a onClick attribute to it.

```
<form action=""  id="form2">
<div>
<input type="text" id="third">
<input type="button" id="submit_form" onclick="checkInput()" value="Submit">
 </div>
</form>
<div>
<input type="text" id="fourth" >
</div>

function checkInput() {  document.getElementById('fourth').value=document.getElementById('third').value;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#form2').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#fourth').val($('#third').val());
             $('#form2').submit();

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form2">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="third" value="ssss">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_form">
  </div>

</form>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="fourth">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```